# Don't show notification when in foreground

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-admin

I'm sending push notification from my node server using the Firebase admin SDK. But on iOS I only want to show the notification when the app is in the background/terminated and not when in the foreground. Currently it will always show the notification.

This is my payload:

```
const payload = {
  data: {
    data: 'data',
    more: 'moreData',
  },
  notification: {
    title: 'Incoming Call',
    body: 'Someone is calling you',
    text: 'This is some text',
    sound: 'default',
    click_action: 'com.example.INCOMING_CALL',
  }
};
const options = {
  priority: 'high',
  time_to_live: 30,
  collapse_key: 'Video Call',
  content_available: true,
};

admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokensList, payload, options);
```

Is it something with my payload or is it something that I have to do in the AppDelegate.swift?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can achieve this in `AppDelegate` by using the `applicationState`,

**In iOS8:**

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {

    if !UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active {
     // Handle your push notification here   
    }

}
```

**In iOS10:**

1. `import UserNotifications` framework
2. Implement `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`
       method

   ```
   func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {


   if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active { // In iOS 10 if app is in foreground do nothing.
       completionHandler([])
   } else { // If app is not active you can show banner, sound and badge.
       completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
   }

   }
   ```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In iOS you decide in AppDelegate.swift, what to do with notifications. In AppDelegate handle the notification for the appropriate case and discard for when app is in foreground.

In iOS 10, to handle notification when app is terminated and you launch the app from the notification, handle it in

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

 if launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] != nil {
     if  let remoteNotif = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? NSDictionary

    } 
 }

}
```

For handling notification for foreground, use this method

```
 func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
     //handle notification here

 }
```

For handling  notification for  background, use this method:

```
 func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
     //handle notification here

 }
```