# willPresentNotification not work as expected

Tags: ios, push-notification

Im work with push notification and did implement method:

```
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler{

    NSLog(@"will-present");
}
```

However, it's called only when notification will present during app active state, not background. Is there any way to proceed callback when notification is about to show and iPhone screen is locked?

Comment: You can follow my answer here for this: [notification handling in iOS 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43801958/dont-show-notification-when-in-foreground/43802168#43802168)

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn on background modes for remote notification in capabilites

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Use this method for handling notification in background

`//handle in this method when app in foreground and background
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                    fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {}`

Answer (score 0):

It appear that behaviour that i need is impossible.

Follow this link to find out more:
[Alarm clock app in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445090/alarm-clock-app-in-ios/9621425#9621425)